# F280021 Wiring Help

Tags: schematics, microprocessor

I just want to make sure that I wired up the power circuit for this F280021 correctly according to the datasheet.

Datasheet:https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tms320f280021.pdf?ts=1628790148836&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTMS320F280021#page=29&zoom=100,0,100

[image]

Answer (score 3):

VDDIO should be on DGND. It is on page 28 of the datasheet. I just place 0.1uF ceramic caps close to each and every power pins if possible, along with the large power bank (bulk) caps.

---

Edit,
Extra tip: Arrangement of AGND & DGND is critical.
Aggregate the "domains" of power (GND, VCC, VDD, VSS). Have those meet at a right place, while "looking" at how the current pass around. Yes, I do steer the current, and you can do as well.